# Using Select2 get error - "Error: No select2/compat/query"

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I am attempting to use the [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) library in my site to leverage `placecomplete` ([following it's rather simple configuration steps here](https://github.com/stephjang/placecomplete)), but when I run the code I get a strange error -

> Error: No select2/compat/query`

I've tried googling it and it really seems like no one else has encountered this?

My code in a nutshell is,

loading the files...

```
<link href="scripts/Select2/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="scripts/Select2/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/jquery.placecomplete.js">//<![CDATA[//]]></script>
```

Tagging an input element in my body...

```
<input id="example123" class="example123" type="text" />
```

In my document.ready function, calling the following code...

```
$('#example123').placecomplete({});
```

and thats where it throws the error.

Any ideas where Im going wrong, and what this error means?

Comment: 1) Did you include jQuery? (sounds dumb but it happens sometimes :) 2) are you sure that the files names are correct and the files are loaded? (Check in your network tab and console)

Comment: Does it really support `input` elements rather than only `select` elements?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

You are running into two issues here, both of which can easily be fixed.

1. Select2 4.0.0 no longer supports the `query` option in the slimmed down, standard build. This must be included in the full build (`select2.full.js`) as it is handled through a backwards compatibility module.
2. You are using Placecomplete and it depends on an older version of Select2. It looks like Select2 3.5.2+ can work, but I can tell from the options that it is using, it cannot work with Select2 4.0.0. [There is an open ticket](https://github.com/stephjang/placecomplete/issues/11) about this for Placecomplete.

Comment: Can you tell me how to require the full version? I have installed `select2` via npm and I have both `select2.js` and `select2.full.js`, I require it as `require('select2');`, how can I do the same to get the full version?

Comment: `require('select2/dist/js/select2.full');` should work

Answer (score 20):

For me, changing the `<input />` tag to a `<select>` tag worked.

Comment: this is the right answer

Answer (score 18):

I've had this when you have two controls on your web page with the same Id - I had a hidden control and a select (the hidden control was first).

Comment: I'm getting this error with two `select2` boxes that have distinct ids.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen if you try to initialize select2 on field type that does not "support" select2, like a hidden field or something along those lines.